# How do I adjust the height of the input in HTML?

Tags: html

I tried many times that google give me answers, but, It not working... Someone help?

I tried:
`<input type="text" height="10">`
`<input type="text" style="min-height: 10px;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this style to height the input element

```css
input {
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text Here"/>
```

Comment: This one is the easiest and the perfect answer for me, Other one is correct to but, I recommend for this  answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```html
<input type="text" style="height:10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

This code you wrote `<input type="text" style="min-height: 10px;">` - does work actually. it just won't go to `min-height` you stated because inside the font for the text is bigger. If you maintain the font correlated with the input height it will work.

This example works if you make the font size smaller.

```html
<input type="text" style="min-height: 5px; font-size: 4px;">
```

Comment: min-height: 5px? i guess you want to write min-height: 50px;

Comment: @Theconcise No, He was trying to make an input smaller than it's original size. and couldn't achieve it because of fon't size inside. this is a proof of concept.

Comment: Alright, even though he didn't state that in the question and also 10px input box height will be tiny

Answer (score 0):

It is not height its size.
If you want in the way you questioned.Something like this help

```
<input type="text" size="10">

<input type="text" size="10px">
```